# TFS Gated Check In Fails due to "has not been mapped"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have a medium sized solution with 8 projects in it.  I've been moving things around to ensure "one-time-one-place".  To do this I created a new project and moved a bunch of stuff from other projects to this "Common" project.

When I check in the code, and override the Gated Check In policy... it acted like it had to do a batch build prior to the check in happening.  I hadn't see this before, but.... the build failed with tons of  "The Item xyz has not be mapped"...

What's best way to fix this?  Should I un-map everything in the solution and remap?  If so do I just delete the mapping and then try to check in the code without the mapping?  Or how do I remap to existing local code that I want to check in..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the mapping for the new project location in the build definitions's Source Settings page:

[image]

Comment: One follow on question, do I get rid of the prior mapping in place before I ran into this problem?

Comment: You need to make sure the source mappings include everything you need to build your solution, but entries that are now redundant after the changes can be removed.